# Slicing Variable in Parfor loop

Tags: matlab

Hi I want to run the code as below using PARFOR.
When I try it says that :

> Valid indices for 'A_x' and 'A_y' are restricted in PARFOR loops.
>   Explanation  For MATLAB to execute parfor loops efficiently, the
>   amount of data sent to the MATLAB workers must be minimal. One of the
>   ways MATLAB achieves this is by restricting the way variables can be
>   indexed in parfor iterations. The indicated variable is indexed in a
>   way that is incompatible with parfor.  Suggested Action
>
> Fix the indexing. For a description of the indexing restrictions, see “Sliced Variables” in the >Parallel Computing Toolbox documentation:

```
 N=eveninteger;
 H=zeros(N);
 V=zeros(N);
 A_x=zeros(N);
 A_y=zeros(N);
    parfor i=1:N;
      for j=1:N;
        if H(i,j)==-2;
          t=0.3;
          As_x=t*(j-i)/a;
          As_y=t*(j-i)/a;


       elseif H(i,j)==-3;
           t=0.8;
          As_x=t*(j-i)/(a*sqrt3);
          As_y=t*(j-i)/(a*sqrt3);

      elseif i==j

               As_x=i;
               As_y=i;
      else
          t=0;
          As_x=0;
          As_y=0;

        end
      for p=1:N/2
        for q=N/2+1:N

             A_x(p,q)=A_x(p,q)+As_x*(V(i,p)*V(j,q));
             A_y(p,q)=A_y(p,q)+As_y*(V(i,p)*V(j,q));


        end
      end
end
```

end

I could not find solution. Could you offer me a solution.
Thanks in advance.
Erico

Comment: Your code is incomplete, at least an "end" is missing. Please indent your code properly, use rightlick->"Smart Indent" in the editor.

Comment: never tried it but having a bunch of `for` loops nested within a `parfor` loop seems awkward. And it seems some of them (nested `for` loops) could be replaced by vectorized expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to perform a "reduction" on `A_x` and `A_y` using `+`. You might be able to work around this by doing something like the following:

```
parfor i = 1:N
  A_x_tmp = zeros(N);
  A_y_tmp = zeros(N);
  for p=1:N/2
    for q=N/2+1:N
      A_x_tmp(p,q) = A_x_tmp(p,q) + ...
      A_y_tmp(p,q) = A_y_tmp(p,q) + ...
    end
  end
  A_x = A_x + A_x_tmp;
  A_y = A_y + A_y_tmp;
end
```

In that way, PARFOR will understand the reduction operations on `A_x` and `A_y`.